# Por qué se queda enciclado un Process en C#

Tags: c#, imagen, archivo, graphviz

Tengo problema al tratar de ejecutar un comando de windows desde una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en c#. El problema es que se queda como enciclado en algo pero no comprendo por qué.

Estoy tratando de crear la imagen de un grafo con sintaxis de graphviz, consultando la información que tengo en el archivo .dot

```
public void graficaDot()
    {
        cgrafica++;
        ArchivoGraphviz archivo1 = new ArchivoGraphviz("archivo" + cgrafica, "dot");
        archivo1.Contenido = archivoDot();
        archivo1.guardar();
        Console.WriteLine(archivo1.Nombre);

        string comando = "dot -Tpng " + archivo1.Nombre + ".dot" + " -o " + archivo1.Nombre + ".png";
        string ruta = archivo1.Ruta;

        generarImagen(comando, ruta);


    }

    public string generarImagen(string comand, string ruta)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",ruta+comand);
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process pro = new Process();
        pro.StartInfo = p;
        pro.Start();

        string v = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        return v;

    }
```

Cabe mencionar que el archivo .dot que estoy consultando, está con la sintaxis correcta, no tiene ningún error, así que esa parte no es.

se queda enciclado después del pro.Start(); pero no comprendo por qué, si alguien pudiese ayudarme, se lo voy a agradecer mucho.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un poco complicado ayudarte ya que no tengo acceso a la aplicación que tratas de ejecutar, pero a ver si te puedo dar unas pistas. Para ejecutar un comando usando `Process.Start` no es necesario que llames a `cmd`, llama directamente a la aplicacion (en este caso `dot`).

Pon el directorio de trabajo en `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`.

Y por ultimo, los parámetros(los archivos en este caso) debes pasarles en `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`. Te pongo un ejemplo basado en [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) adaptado a como debería ser tu código mas o menos:

```
ProcessStartInfo p= new ProcessStartInfo("dot.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory= @"C:\dot" //aqui el directorio de trabajo
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.UseShellExecute = false;
p.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Arguments = "-Tpng " + archivo1.Nombre + ".dot" + " -o " + archivo1.Nombre + ".png";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Exactamente con esta sugerencia se resolvió el problema, muy agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que el buffer de la propiedad **Process.StandardOutput** se este llenando y generando un deadlock.

Según la documentacion de Microsoft: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

> // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then
>   wait. string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); p.WaitForExit();

Necesitas agregar `p.WaitForExit();` después de la línea string `v = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`.

Abajo publico el código modificado:

```
public void graficaDot()
{
    cgrafica++;
    ArchivoGraphviz archivo1 = new ArchivoGraphviz("archivo" + cgrafica, "dot");
    archivo1.Contenido = archivoDot();
    archivo1.guardar();
    Console.WriteLine(archivo1.Nombre);

    string comando = "dot -Tpng " + archivo1.Nombre + ".dot" + " -o " + archivo1.Nombre + ".png";
    string ruta = archivo1.Ruta;

    generarImagen(comando, ruta);


}

public string generarImagen(string comand, string ruta)
{

    ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",ruta+comand);
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    Process pro = new Process();
    pro.StartInfo = p;
    pro.Start();
    string v = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    // Agrega esta linea para esperar a que termine el proceso.
    p.WaitForExit();

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Ya modifiqué lo indicado pero sigue pasando lo mismo.